# Using Firebase Anonymous Authentication, error, invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently when trying to sign in anonymously with Firebase I get the following error

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION","errors":[{"message":"ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}

The function I am calling is the one provided in the docs

```
doSignInAnonymously = () => {

   this.auth.signInAnonymously()
}
```

I don't understand the error code as Error 400 means an Invalid JSON in your request:

> Check that the JSON message is properly formatted and contains valid
>   fields (for instance, making sure the right data type is passed in).

I am using a function provided by the API so I don't know how I could have implemented it wrong, or what exactly it means when it says `ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION`, why would signing in anonymously have anything to do with an admin?

Does anyone have any experience with this type of error or can see any obvious errors in my use of the function ?

my firebase.js file where I have all my authentication functions.

```js
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
}

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    /* Helper */

    this.fieldValue = app.firestore.FieldValue;
    this.emailAuthProvider = app.auth.EmailAuthProvider;

    /* Firebase APIs */

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.firestore();
  }

  // *** Auth API ***

  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  doSignInAnonymously = () => {

    this.auth.signInAnonymously()
  }
```

Code at the call site:

```html
<Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => firebase
              .doSignInAnonymously()
              .then(({ user }) => {
                localStorage.setItem(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_STORAGE, JSON.stringify(user))
                history.push(ROUTES.USER)
               })
              .catch(({ message }) => setErrMessage(message))
        }
>
Continue As Guest
</Button>
```

- I tried removing the following line as the error is related to a malformed JSON, but this does't seem to help.

```
localStorage.setItem(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_STORAGE, JSON.stringify(user))
```

Comment: Can you post more of your authentication code? Specifically, which firebase methods you use?

Comment: question is updated

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting same error

Comment: Yes, a developer I hired has disabled Anonymous Authentication, so make sure you have this method turned on in the Firebase dashboard

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to [Firebase console](http://console.firebase.com) and check your **Sign-in providers** under the **Sign-in Methods** tab in the **Authentication** service and make sure *Anonymous* is enabled.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct response